# How to union two tables and extract first record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two stock trading related intraday tables:

1. Best bid and ask with quantity and timestamp
2. Trade table with traded price and quantity

Example (just fake prices and quantities):

Trade Table

```
char, char, integer, number, number

Ticker   time,   milliseconds    price   qty
MSFT  09:10:02      800          23.45   10
MSFT  09:10:02      900          23.45    5
MSFT  09:10:06      600          23.42    1
```

Best bid ask table

```
char, char, integer, number, number, number, number

Ticker   time   milliseconds     bid  bid_qty   ask   ask_qty
MSFT   09:10:02     850         23.42   50     23.45    4
MSFT   09:10:02     930         23.44   50     23.45    1
MSFT   09:10:02     980         23.41   49     23.45    1
MSFT   09:10:06     600         23.42   45     23.43    2
MSFT   09:10:06     700         23.42   25     23.43    2
MSFT   09:10:06     710         23.41   20     23.43    2
```

Question: Starting with trade timestamp I want to find the FIRST subsequent best bid best ask  record after this trade was made. In other words: this trade caused next order book situation.

How the proper SQL statement should look like?

Important:

- trade table records are far less than best bid ask records
- time is formated as charakter, milliseconds are stored in a separate column as integer
- timestamp (time + millisecond) of the best bid best ask can be the same as of a trade or a couple of milliseconds later (but not earlier!).

So in my example above I need to have the following joined query result:

```
Ticker time    milliseconds price qty ba_time  ba_milliseconds bid    bid_qty ask   ask_qty
 MSFT  09:10:02    800      23.45 10  09:10:02       850       23.42    50    23.45    4
 MSFT  09:10:02    900      23.45  5  09:10:02       930       23.44    50    23.45    1
 MSFT  09:10:06    600      23.42  1  09:10:06       600       23.42    45    23.43    2
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is no PK, FK constraint on the tables, rite?

Comment: Yes, correct, unfortunately no PK/FK in my tables, I need to compare timestamps

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a620f/1)

```
with trade as (
    select
        ticker,
        format('%s.%s', "time", milliseconds)::time(3) as "time",
        price,
        qty
    from trade
), bba as (
    select
        ticker,
        format('%s.%s', "time", milliseconds)::time(3) as "time",
        bid,
        bid_qty,
        ask,
        ask_qty
    from bba
)
select distinct on (rn)
    t.ticker, t.time, t.price, t.qty,
    b.time as ba_time, b.bid, b.bid_qty, b.ask, b.ask_qty
from
    (
        select *,
            row_number() over(order by "time") as rn
        from trade
    ) t
    inner join
    bba b on t.ticker = b.ticker and t."time" <= b."time"
order by rn, b.time
```

You will need the day in the timestamp if the table will have more than one day.